# Error when creating a vcf file in android

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do is to generate a .vcf file to SD card! But I am getting this exception. Can someone help me out.

[image: The exception thrown]

The code I have using is below I dont know why it is giving

> java.io.IOException: read failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)

```
public class Homepage extends ActionBarActivity {
Cursor cursor;
ArrayList<String> vCard ;
String vfile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    final TextView re = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_hp);

}


public void createAndBackUp(View view) {

    Thread createVCF = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                vfile = "backUpSiv.vcf";
                getVcardString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    createVCF.start();

}

public void getVcardString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

            get(cursor);
            Log.d("TAG",
                    "Contact " + (i + 1) + "VcF String is" + vCard.get(i));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
    }

}

public void get(Cursor cursor) {

    // cursor.moveToFirst();
    String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
    try {
        fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
        fis.read(buf);
        String vcardstring = new String(buf);
        vCard.add(vcardstring);

        String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + File.separator + vfile;
        FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                storage_path, true);
        mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You are getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException in getVcardString(), too. Maybe this is the problem? (last line of your screenshot)

Comment: Can you help me out?

Comment: Could you update your question with the whole crash stacktrace (copied from your logcat output? Otherwise I will have to guess the problem (I think vCard.get() will fail). 
And you could try to find out if your exception in get() is thrown. This would definitively cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException for vCard.get()

Comment: you should check your url in Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey), too. Maybe you have some invalid characters there

Comment: The Exception is thrown in get() @Sprigg

Comment: fis.read(buf);  

is what creating the error I dont know why! I have logged line by line and stuck with this IOException @Sprigg

Comment: dir you check your uri? What does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to create Vcard,

```
public static String getVcard(String lookupKey, Context context, String filename) {
    final String vfile = filename + ".vcf";

    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI,
            lookupKey);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fd = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
        fis.read(buf);
        String VCard = new String(buf);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + File.separator + "Demo-vcard" + File.separator;

        File file = new File(path);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        path = path + vfile;

        mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path,
                true);
        mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());

        return path;
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (mFileOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                mFileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```